# Imported geojson has different bbox than manually created csv of point features

Tags: r, r-sf

I can't figure out what's going on with these two files, I think it's a projection issue, or maybe I need a new polygon.

data:

```
library(sf)
provinces <- st_read("https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/ca/ca-all.geo.json")
provinces <- st_transform(provinces, 4326)

pts <- tribble(~Name, ~lat, ~lng,
               "Kelowna",49.9,-119.483333,
               "Beaumont",53.352436,-113.415313,
               "Edmonton",53.55,-113.5,
               "Paradise",47.526367,-52.871569,
               "Toronto",43.651653,-79.382898)

pts <- st_as_sf(pts, coords = c("lng", "lat"), crs = 4326 )
```

shows as such wit the polygons clearly too small (should be the provinces of Canada):

```
leaflet(provinces) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  addPolygons() %>% 
  addMarkers(data = pts)
```

[image]

The structure shows the bboxes are different but the projections are the same:

```
> print(provinces)
Simple feature collection with 14 features and 22 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -96.01125 ymin: 40.00688 xmax: -95.8891 ymax: 40.08523
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs

> print(pts)
Simple feature collection with 5 features and 1 field
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -119.4833 ymin: 43.65165 xmax: -52.87157 ymax: 53.55
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
# A tibble: 5 x 2
```

How do I get these two on the same page?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure the polygons from highcharts are broken for some reason, or at least they are not in the projection that they say they are. EPSG 102002 is supposed to be in [metres](https://epsg.io/102002), but the coordinates for those polygons extend on the order of  10000 units, which would be too small for provinces. (check st_bbox before transforming)

Comment: Okay - so I'm not entirely crazy. I'll try to find better polygons if these can't be used

Comment: Looking at the highcharts demo using those polygons, it has no base map, so they probably ignored the projection since it wouldn't matter :/